# Error "No such file or directory exists" while trying to create directory and save images to file manager

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I am trying to save images locally by saving them to the FileManager. Somehow it is not working and I don't know why.

`helloid` is the id of the event I am trying to retrieve images from.
First I am getting the image and then I try to save it locally.

```
func retrieveAllPictures(helloid: String) async {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        var contains = false
        let result = try? await db.collection("events").document(helloid).getDocument()
        
        if(result?.data() != nil){
            allPictureIDs = (result?.data()!["pictures"] as? [String])!
        }
        
        for i in allPictureIDs {
            if(i == helloid) {
                contains = true
            }
        }
        if(allPictureIDs != nil){
        for pathOfIds in allPictureIDs {
            let storage = Storage.storage().reference()
            let fileRef = storage.child(pathOfIds)
            
            
            //Split path to get actual name of the image
            let components = pathOfIds.components(separatedBy: "/")
            let pathForFileManager = components[1]
            //print(pathForFileManager)
            
            do {
                let data : Data = try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation  { continuation in
                    fileRef.getData(maxSize: 5000 * 1024) { data, error in
                        if let error = error {
                            continuation.resume(throwing: error)
                        } else {
                            continuation.resume(returning: data!)
                        }
                    }
                }
                let imageFinal = UIImage(data: data)!
                self.retrievedEventImages.append(imageFinal)
                
                let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
                let myCustomDirectory = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("directory_\(helloid)")
                print(myCustomDirectory)
                
                //checking if directory already exists
                if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: myCustomDirectory.path) {
                    do {
                        try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: myCustomDirectory, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
                    
                    } catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
                    
                    let imageURL = myCustomDirectory.appendingPathComponent("\(pathForFileManager)")
                    if let imgData = imageFinal.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0){
                        do {
                            try imgData.write(to: imageURL)
                        } catch {
                            print(error)
                        }
                    }
                    
                } else {
                    let imageURL = myCustomDirectory.appendingPathComponent("\(pathForFileManager)")
                    //checking if file already exists in directory, if not add it to the directory
                    
                        if let imgData = imageFinal.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0){
                            do {
                                try imgData.write(to: imageURL)
                            } catch {
                                print(error)
                            }
                        }
                }} catch {
            print(error)
            }
        }} else {
            self.retrievedEventImages.append(UIImage(systemName: "x.circle"))
        }
}
```

This code works fine but somehow I can't append the images to a list (to display them afterwards)

```
/// This view is the eventual view which shows the content of an event
struct FinalEventView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: AppViewModel
    var id: String
    @State var selectedImage: UIImage?
    @State var isPickerShowing = false
    @State private var isShowingQRView = false
    @State var images: [UIImage] = []


    var body: some View {
        VStack{
                NavigationLink(destination: ShowQRCodeView(eventid: self.id), isActive: $isShowingQRView) {
                    EmptyView()
                }
                VStack {
                    Image(uiImage: viewModel.finalPP)
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 90, height: 90, alignment: .center)
                        .cornerRadius(50)
                    Text("\(viewModel.finalName)")
                }//Profile picture and Text
                Divider()
////////////////////////////////////   ////////////////////////////////////   ////////////////////////////////////   ////////////////////////////////////   ////////////////////////////////////
            ScrollView{
                ForEach(self.images, id: \.self){ image in
                    Image(uiImage: image)
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 360, height: 370)
                        .cornerRadius(50)
                }
            }.sheet(isPresented: $isPickerShowing, onDismiss: nil) {
                ImagePicker(selectedImage: $selectedImage, isPickerShowing: $isPickerShowing)}//Images
////////////////////////////////////   ////////////////////////////////////   ////////////////////////////////////   ////////////////////////////////////   ////////////////////////////////////
            
                .toolbar(content: {
                    //Plus to add image
                    ToolbarItem() {
                        Button(action: {
                            isPickerShowing = true
                            self.selectedImage = nil
                        }, label: {
                            Image(systemName: "plus")
                        })
                        .frame(alignment: .trailing)
                    }//end toolbarItem1
                    
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                                           Button(action: {
                                               Task {
                                                   try? await viewModel.uploadOtherPicture(plusoneid: self.id, image: self.selectedImage!)
                                                   try? await viewModel.retrieveAllPictures(helloid: self.id)
                                                   
                                                   selectedImage = nil
                                               }
                                           }, label: {
                                                   Text("upload chosen image")
                                               })
                                       }
                    ToolbarItem(){
                        Menu(content: {
                            Button(action: {
                                isShowingQRView = true
                            }, label: {
                                Text("Show QR-Code")
                                Image(systemName: "list.bullet")})
                            Button(action: {
                                var TODO = true
                            }, label: {
                                Text("Delete event")
                                Image(systemName: "trash")
                            })
                        }, label:  {
                            Label("PDF", systemImage: "list.bullet")
                        })
                    }//end toolbarItem2
                })//end toolbar
            
            }//end VStack
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
            .onAppear{
                Task {
                    try? await viewModel.retrievePP(helloid: self.id)
                    try? await viewModel.retrieveAllPictures(helloid: self.id)
                    try? await viewModel.getName(id: self.id)
                    try? await viewModel.getEvents()}
                
                let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
                let myCustomDirectory = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("\(id)")
                do {
                    let contents = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: myCustomDirectory, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: [])
                    for item in contents {
                        if let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: item.path) {
                            self.images.append(image)
                        }
                    }
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }

                
            }
        }//end body
    }//end struct
```

When I try to debug it, it skips

```
for item in contents {
                        if let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: item.path) {
                            self.images.append(image)
                        }
                    }
```

I feel like it tries to save the images to contents but somehow fails but I am not sure why

I am trying to retrieve the images from Firebase Storage and save them to the file manager.

Comment: FYI - you are not saving them to the file manager. You are trying to save the files to the Documents folder using `FileManager`.

Comment: The first error seems to be unrelated to the code you posted since it's about CIFilters. But look closely at the related error. Look at the path. You have the `xBFcVvTJbnmB5ZxY1E1y` on there twice but you only create the folder for the first instance of it.

Comment: @HangarRash I saw that too but I can't figure out where I create a second instance at all

Comment: Probably from `pathOfIds`. Print that value out or look at it in the debugger.

Comment: @HangarRash you were right, the pathOfIds contained the directory name as well so the final path had a duplicate of the directory path
I edited the question, now I am trying to save the images to an array but it somehow still doesn't work.... I am not getting an error at the func retrieveAllPictures but at the finalEventView... do you maybe know why?